# Checkbox issues in wpf mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, checkbox

I have the problem when I using `CheckBox` in my `GridView` using WPF and MVVM.

```
 <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                     <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
                   </DataTemplate>
  </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
```

My ViewModel

```
 public bool IsSelected
    {
        get
        {
            return _isSelected;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_isSelected == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            _isSelected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
        }
    }
```

How I can select the data in a selected row, i.e. the `CheckBox` value of that row is true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to set up a `IEnumerable<bool>`/`IEnumerable<SomeClass>` that holds the `IsChecked` information for each of your `CheckBox`es. Something like

```
public class CheckedItem
{
    public CheckedItem() { }

    public CheckedItem(string text, bool isChecked) : this()
    {
        this._text = text;
        this._isChecked = isChecked;
    }

    private string _text;
    public String Text;
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set
        {
            if (_text == value)
                return;
            _text = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
        }
    }

    private bool _isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected;
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set
        {
            if (_isSelected == value)
                return;
            _isSelected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
        }
    }
}

private ObservableCollection<CheckedItem> checkItemCollection = 
    new ObservableCollection<CheckedItem>();
public ObservableCollection<CheckedItem> CheckItemCollection
{
    get { return checkItemCollection; }
    set
    {
        if (checkItemCollection == value)
            return;
        checkItemCollection = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("CheckItemCollection");
    }
}
```

in XAML you can then bind the `GridView` to this using

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CheckedItemCollection, 
                                Mode=TwoWay, 
                                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                                IsAsync=True}" 
    <GridView.Columns>
        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Text}" 
                          IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, 
                                              Mode=TwoWay, 
                                              UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                                              IsAsync=True}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    </GridView.Columns>
</GridView>
```

This was done without an IDE so you may have to tweak this to get it to work.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Sir, then how to check a particular row is checked or unchecked? ie, the value of checkbox is true or false?

Comment: You can look up the row like `CheckedItemCollection[someRowIndex].IsChecked`... The collection should remain in the order you placed the items in. It the row index can change via the UI, then you will have to add a index holder to the `SomeClass` class...